# What's a type for any valid JSX attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Looking for a definition for `AnyValidAttributes` in:

```
const Component = (props: AnyValidAttributes) => (
  <div {...props}>
    example
  </div>
)
```

Comment: This question could use some more detail. It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is rendering a `div`, and you are passing `props` to it. The more generic and yet safe type of `props` would be `HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`:

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

const Component = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => (
  <div {...props}>example</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

"ReactNode" should be valid for any JSX attribute.